# With Sharepoint 2007, how to update a datasheet from a program?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

I writing a tool to automatically update a datasheet on a sharepoint 2007 site. The tool runs on JVM, and seems like 2007 has no REST service support, so can anyone point me to some good resource of using webservice to update datasheet object on sharepoint?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The DataSheet is just a UI view in front of a SharePoint list, therefore you should be looking to update the List, not the DataSheet UI.

This will give you a start, its written for C# but can be ported to Java.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms440289(v=office.12).aspx

> This programming task shows how to use
>   the UpdateListItems method of the
>   Lists Web service to update items in a
>   list through a Microsoft Windows
>   application.

For Java specific example see - http://davidsit.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/creating-sharepoint-list-items-with-java-tutorial/